# How to draw with multiple fingers in canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, multi-touch

I am using android `Canvas` class from creating a drawing application. This is my first attempt to work with the Canvas class. So far the code that I used is working fine and the drawing is working fine. But what I realized in this code is that it allow the user to draw with one finger only, I mean to say if the user used more then one finger to draw on canvas it doesn't allow the user to draw with multiple fingers. I go through documentation regarding multiple touch events but failed to implement it in my code. So can anyone help me to figure this out?

**The code I used for drawing on canvas:**

```
public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener 
{
    private Canvas      m_Canvas;
    
    private Path        m_Path;
    
    private Paint       m_Paint;
    
    ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>> arrayListPaths = new ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>>();
    
    ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>>(); 
    
    private float mX, mY;
    
    private Bitmap bitmapToCanvas;
    
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
        
    public DrawView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);      
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        
        onCanvasInitialization();
    }      
    
    public void onCanvasInitialization()
    {
        m_Paint = new Paint();
        m_Paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        m_Paint.setDither(true);
        m_Paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#37A1D1"));
        m_Paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        m_Paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        m_Paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        m_Paint.setStrokeWidth(2);      
                
        m_Path = new Path();    
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) 
    {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        
        bitmapToCanvas = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        m_Canvas = new Canvas(bitmapToCanvas);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {    
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapToCanvas, 0f, 0f, null);
        canvas.drawPath(m_Path, m_Paint);
    }
    
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) 
    {
        undonePaths.clear();
        m_Path.reset();
        m_Path.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
    
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) 
    {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) 
        {
            m_Path.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }
    private void touch_up() 
    {
        m_Path.lineTo(mX, mY);
                
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        m_Canvas.drawPath(m_Path, m_Paint);
        
        // kill this so we don't double draw                    
        Paint newPaint = new Paint(m_Paint); // Clones the mPaint object
        arrayListPaths.add(new Pair<Path, Paint>(m_Path, newPaint));
        m_Path = new Path();
    }
}
```

I tried making changes in my code to support multiple touch, but it doesn't work properly. [This is my changed code.](http://pastebin.com/W6qvpYGW)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Making Sense of Multitouch](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html), it helped me a lot. It explanes how to handle multi touches

Points to remember

1.Make sure that you switch on `action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK`

2.if you want to draw multiple lines at same time, follow PointerId of each pointer which comes in MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN  and release it in  MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP by comparing pointer ids.

```
private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

// The ‘active pointer’ is the one currently moving our object.
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

// Existing code ...

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;

        // Save the ID of this pointer
        mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its position
        final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
        final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
        final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

        final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
        final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

        mPosX += dx;
        mPosY += dy;

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;

        invalidate();
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
        // Extract the index of the pointer that left the touch sensor
        final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
        final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
        if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
            // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
            // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
            final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
            mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
        }
        break;
    }
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Edit**

Please see this code... This still has some issues but i think you can debug it and fix those ... Also the logic is not there persisting lines  please implement that...

```
package com.example.stackgmfdght;

import java.util.ArrayList;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Pair;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class JustDoIt extends View
{
    private Canvas          m_Canvas;

 //   private Path            m_Path;

    int current_path_count=-1; 
    ArrayList <Path> m_Path_list =  new ArrayList<Path>();
    ArrayList <Float> mX_list =  new ArrayList<Float>();
    ArrayList <Float> mY_list =  new ArrayList<Float>();
    ArrayList <Integer> mActivePointerId_list =  new ArrayList<Integer>();

    private Paint       m_Paint;

    ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>> arrayListPaths = new ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>>();

    //ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>>();

    private float mX, mY;

    private Bitmap bitmapToCanvas;

    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    public JustDoIt (Context context)
    {
            super(context);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true);      

            onCanvasInitialization();
    }     

    public JustDoIt(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);      

        onCanvasInitialization();
    }

    public void onCanvasInitialization()
    {
            m_Paint = new Paint();
            m_Paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            m_Paint.setDither(true);
            m_Paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#37A1D1"));
            m_Paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            m_Paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            m_Paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            m_Paint.setStrokeWidth(2);            

         //   m_Path = new Path();  
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

            bitmapToCanvas = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            m_Canvas = new Canvas(bitmapToCanvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {    
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapToCanvas, 0f, 0f, null);
            for(int i=0;i<=current_path_count;i++)
            {
            canvas.drawPath(m_Path_list.get(i), m_Paint);
            }
    }


    public void onDrawCanvas()
    {
            for (Pair<Path, Paint> p : arrayListPaths)
            {
                m_Canvas.drawPath(p.first, p.second);
            }
    }

    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

    // The ‘active pointer’ is the one currently moving our object.
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;



    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
            super.onTouchEvent(event);

            final int action = event.getAction();  

            switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
            {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    {
                            float x = event.getX();
                            float y = event.getY();


                            current_path_count=0;
                            mActivePointerId_list.add ( event.getPointerId(0),current_path_count);                                              
                            touch_start((x ),(y ),current_path_count );
                    }
                    break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    {

           if(event.getPointerCount()>current_path_count)
           {

                            current_path_count++;
                            float x = event.getX(current_path_count);
                            float y = event.getY(current_path_count);


                            mActivePointerId_list.add ( event.getPointerId(current_path_count),current_path_count);                                              
                                touch_start((x ),(y ),current_path_count);  
           } 
                    }
                    break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    {
                         for(int i=0;i<=current_path_count;i++)
                         { try{
                                     int pointerIndex = event
                                    .findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId_list.get(i));

                                    float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
                                    float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

                                    touch_move((x ),(y ),i);
                         }
                         catch(Exception e)
                         {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                         }


                    }
                    break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    { current_path_count=-1; 
                         for(int i=0;i<=current_path_count;i++)
                         {

                                    touch_up(i);
                         }
                         mActivePointerId_list =  new ArrayList<Integer>();


                    }
                    break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    {
                            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;  
                            current_path_count=-1; 
                    }
                    break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    {
                            final int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                            final int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                            for(int i=0;i<=current_path_count;i++)
                         {
                            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId_list.get(i))
                            {
                                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.

                                     mActivePointerId_list.remove(i);
                                    touch_up(i);
                                    break;
                            }              
                         }
                    }    
                    break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                    break;
    }

    invalidate();
    return true;
}

    private void touch_start(float x, float y, int count)
    {
        //    undonePaths.clear();
           Path  m_Path=new Path();

           m_Path_list.add(count,m_Path);

           m_Path_list.get(count).reset();


           m_Path_list.get(count).moveTo(x, y);

            mX_list.add(count,x);
            mY_list.add(count,y);

    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y,int count)
    {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX_list.get(count));
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY_list.get(count));
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE)
            {
                    m_Path_list.get(count).quadTo(mX_list.get(count), mY_list.get(count), (x + mX_list.get(count))/2, (y + mY_list.get(count))/2);
                    try{

                        mX_list.remove(count);
                        mY_list.remove(count);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    mX_list.add(count,x);
                    mY_list.add(count,y);
            }
    }
    private void touch_up(int count)
    {
         m_Path_list.get(count).lineTo(mX_list.get(count), mY_list.get(count));

            // commit the path to our offscreen
            m_Canvas.drawPath( m_Path_list.get(count), m_Paint);

            // kill this so we don't double draw                          
            Paint newPaint = new Paint(m_Paint); // Clones the mPaint object
            arrayListPaths.add(new Pair<Path, Paint>( m_Path_list.get(count), newPaint));
            m_Path_list.remove(count);
            mX_list.remove(count);
            mY_list.remove(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i go through this doc, But in the doc they mention that to register multiple touch we need MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN, But in their example code they never used that, and secondly if u don't mind can u please help me to implement it in my code. Actually i tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: I make the changes in my code as ur suggestion but it crash everytime i draw even with one finger http://pastebin.com/uKwz24y5

Comment: In your code ACTION_DOWN is left empty, you can get the pointer id from Action_down itself  because ACTION_DOWN will be the first event  in any course of touch event , then on wards for each other finger down ACTION_POINTER_DOWN will be called. You need to get the count of pointer then calculate the index  of pointers and manage them in ACTION_POINTER_DOWN and ACTION_POINTER_UP.  it can take some time to implement it perfectly....

Comment: Yeh u r right when i remove the code from ACTION_POINTER_DOWN to ACTION_DOWN the crash issue is solved, but still it don't allow to draw with multiple hand. But one thing i notice is that, suppose i put one finger down and then another finger down, now when i remove both my finger it draw a line between two finger, I really stuck in this from last couple of days, can u help me to sort this out. This is the updated code without crash http://pastebin.com/TkPNVfjj

Comment: To draw with multiple finger at the same time you need to have multiple paths for each finger and update the paths in MOVE event. The problem of drawing a line between two finger is because that you are not checking the pointer id in Move Action Just make sure that you call touch_move with appropriate touch events with verified pointer ID if here is change in pointer ID start drawing other path..  Hope you can understand this... Just spend more time with the code running  it on device... Once you understand the  hierarchic of events it will become more clear.

Comment: You believe it or not. I am trying this code from last three days, but still no success, I really tried a lot and put my all effort on it, But still confused what to do. At least if u know the solution, help me to sort this out. It will be really greatfull to u.

Comment: Let me try to implement a small sample for you

Comment: See the edit I implemented it by combining multi touch and your code

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..i made the changes as far u suggested, but still it allow me to draw with one finger only. If i used another finger it doesn't draw anything with that finger. Is anything i miss, check my code http://pastebin.com/mrA7uEwn

Comment: See the new code ... i am not saying it is perfect but you can make it perfect..... :-)

Comment: Thanks thomas..u help me a lot..i will try and let u know...thanks again dude

Comment: Always welcome ... If you have some success please share your code... HELP OTHERS ...HELP YOURSELF  :-)

Comment: Hey thomas i used ur code and made some changes, and its working fine ,but only in one case it crash. Suppose i put two of my finger down and start drawing, now i put up one of the finger up, and again put that finger down, then at that time it crash. saying pointer index out of range. I debug but unable to find where the issue is

Comment: I think you need to modify code  MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:  Sorry that i cant do the debug, i am having lot of work today..... messed up week end ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Since there is no answer with working code, I can share a working example. The key is to have an array of currently active pointer ids and their paths. It is also important to know that in case of multiple moving pointers, onTouchEvent gets called only once for all of them and you need to iterate through all of the pointers to draw their new positions.

```
public class DrawView extends View {

    private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap;

    private SparseArray<Path> paths;

    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setupDrawing();
    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setupDrawing();
    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setupDrawing();
    }

    private void setupDrawing() {
        paths = new SparseArray<>();

        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

        canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
        for (int i=0; i<paths.size(); i++) {
            canvas.drawPath(paths.valueAt(i), drawPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int index = event.getActionIndex();
        int id = event.getPointerId(index);

        Path path;
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                path = new Path();
                path.moveTo(event.getX(index), event.getY(index));
                paths.put(id, path);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                for (int i=0; i<event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
                    id = event.getPointerId(i);
                    path = paths.get(id);
                    if (path != null) path.lineTo(event.getX(i), event.getY(i));
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                path = paths.get(id);
                if (path != null) {
                    drawCanvas.drawPath(path, drawPaint);
                    paths.remove(id);
                }
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is the for loop needed for ACTION_MOVE? I would have thought each finger would fire this listener independently?

Comment: This listener only gets fired independently for UP and DOWN events, but not for MOVE events. For simultaneous MOVE events it will only fire once, that's why you need to loop through all the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Here example for copy-paste. Just create class that extend View and implement following methods.

```
private final Paint paint = new Paint(); // Don't forgot to init color, form etc.

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (int size = paths.size(), i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Path path = paths.get(i);
        if (path != null) {
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
    }
}

private HashMap<Integer, Float> mX = new HashMap<Integer, Float>();
private HashMap<Integer, Float> mY = new HashMap<Integer, Float>();
private HashMap<Integer, Path> paths = new HashMap<Integer, Path>();

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();

    Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent");

    switch (maskedAction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
            for (int size = event.getPointerCount(), i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                Path p = new Path();
                p.moveTo(event.getX(i), event.getY(i));
                paths.put(event.getPointerId(i), p);
                mX.put(event.getPointerId(i), event.getX(i));
                mY.put(event.getPointerId(i), event.getY(i));
            }
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            for (int size = event.getPointerCount(), i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                Path p = paths.get(event.getPointerId(i));
                if (p != null) {
                    float x = event.getX(i);
                    float y = event.getY(i);
                    p.quadTo(mX.get(event.getPointerId(i)), mY.get(event.getPointerId(i)), (x + mX.get(event.getPointerId(i))) / 2,
                            (y + mY.get(event.getPointerId(i))) / 2);
                    mX.put(event.getPointerId(i), event.getX(i));
                    mY.put(event.getPointerId(i), event.getY(i));
                }
            }
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            for (int size = event.getPointerCount(), i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                Path p = paths.get(event.getPointerId(i));
                if (p != null) {
                    p.lineTo(event.getX(i), event.getY(i));
                    invalidate();
                    paths.remove(event.getPointerId(i));
                    mX.remove(event.getPointerId(i));
                    mY.remove(event.getPointerId(i));
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why is the for loop needed for  three ACTION events? I would have thought each finger would fire this listener independently?